AutoRefresh/Logout in Directus SDK fails (400 Bad Request - refresh_token is required in either JSON payload or Cookie)
I am trying to set up an authentication logic using Directus SDK and Next.js for the front end.
Here is the directus.js which contains the initial SDK configuration:

const directus = createDirectus(url)
  .with(authentication("cookie", {credentials: "include", autoRefresh: true, msRefreshBeforeExpires: 5000}))
  .with(rest({credentials: "include"}));

export default directus;

I have also created an auth.js file that hosts all the authentication related methods:
export const directusLogin = async (credentials) => {
  const response = await directus.login(credentials.email, credentials.password, {mode: 'cookie'});
  return response;
};
 
export const directusLogout = async() => {
  await directus.logout();
}

export const directusRefresh = async() => {
  await directus.refresh();
}

Finally I have added the following variables in the .env file:
ACCESS_TOKEN_TTL='2m'
REFRESH_TOKEN_TTL='6m'
CORS_ENABLED='true'
CORS_ORIGIN='true'
CORS_ALLOWED_HEADERS='Content-Type, Authorization, Cookie, Set-Cookie'
REFRESH_TOKEN_COOKIE_DOMAIN='app.domain'
REFRESH_TOKEN_COOKIE_SECURE='false'
REFRESH_TOKEN_COOKIE_SAME_SITE='lax'

However both (auto)refresh and logout methods are failed and the error indicates that the refresh_token is not sent as a cookie in the Directus.
I have tried to perform requests with Directus RESTful API instead of SDK, so I can manually pass the refresh_token in the request headers as a Cookie, but it didn't work either.
const response = await fetch(`${url}/auth/refresh`, {
     method: "POST",
     credentials: "include",
     headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Cookie": `refresh_token=${token}`
     }
});


No Cookie was sent through the request. Same goes for logout.
I have also tried it through different browsers but with the same outcome.
I am expecting this issue to be related with the initial configuration of Directus container (any of the .env vaiabled maybe?)

Did you find a solution to this?
Having similar problem - login(email, pw) works (note using default json mode) but logout() gives error of Invalid payload. The refresh token is required in either the payload or cookie.
Except that refresh token is not returned during login.
